# Profile doesn't match any valid certificate/private-key pair in the default keychain

Tags: ios, ios-provisioning

I am developing an application for a company, they gave me the admin role so I can edit provisioning files. I am getting "Valid signing identity not found for distribution file" and "Profile doesn't match any valid certificate/private-key pair in the default keychain" error on XCode, normally I would revoke the distribution profile by creating a key chain from my mac, but the company have other applications and I can not risk revoking it because clicking revoke gives the following warning.

"Revoking this certificate may invalidate one or more Provisioning Profiles in the Program Portal. Provisioning Profiles already installed on devices will continue to run until the provisioning profile expires."

Is there a way to add a new key pair without revoking the distribution certificate, would revoking the current certificate effect other applications or are there any other solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need the private key associated with the distribution certificate.

Request the person who created the distribution certificate for the company for the private key associated with the distribution certificate. Get him to export the private key from his keychain! Ask him to remember to select both the distribution certificate and private key together before right clicking and exporting it as .p12 [Select both the distribution certificate and private key together before right clicking and exporting it as .p12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dl74h.png)

Once you open the .p12 it should pair up with the distribution certificate (the .cer file you should already have in your keychain). Your provisioning profile should work fine then!

Let me know if it works!

Comment: Our team got a little confused when we went looking for distribution certificates with their private keys attached, it may be worth while pointing out that only agents and admins can create distribution (adhoc) profiles, not team members.

Answer (score 3):

I came across the same issue and for some bizarre reason the method clearwater82 suggested didn't work.

But I found out this documentation on apple developer site. Might be helpful for someone else. It's just two simple steps.

[FIRST STEP : Exporting Your Code Signing Assets to Your File System](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-devices_organizer/articles/export_signing_assets.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010392-CH8)

[SECOND STEP : Importing Your Code Signing Assets from Your File System](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-devices_organizer/articles/import_signing_assets.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010392-CH9)

Hope this helps someone!