# Distribution Provision no private key found

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I downloaded the Distribution provision certificate, the ios_distribution certificate and the aps_production.cer for push notifications.  I installed them all in the key chain.  The primary Distribution certificate does not have a private key with it.  My development certificate does and has worked fine.  It's similar to the linked issue but I've done those steps.

[Stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11122046/profile-doesnt-match-any-valid-certificate-private-key-pair-in-the-default-keyc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the .p12 file which correspond to the private key associated to your certificate when you first created it in the keychain app.

You probably are working on a different Mac that the one used to generate the public/private keys. You just have to export it and then import it on the new Mac.

Comment: Same mac I used for development.  I have the private key associated with the Developer certificate.  Could I some how tie that to the Distribution cert?  Also nothing is expired.  The only unique thing is that we're partnered with a different company and they've already had a distribution of a different App ID.  Would I have to use the exported key from their mac?

Comment: If you're using their Distribution Certificate you have to ask them to export their private key (.p12 file) to get the app working. But if it's not their distribution certificate I'm don't know where the problem is... :/

Comment: That's probably it, I uploaded my stuff for our AppID but distribution may be different.