# Provisioning for Distribution

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch, provisioning-profile, xcode4.6

I can run the app fine through the *development* profile but I can't run it through the *distribution* profile. I have everything setup correctly as far as I can tell. The error that I get from xcode on compile is:

```
Code Sign error: No unexpired provisioning profiles found that contain any of the keychain's signing certificates
```

and in `TARGETS` > `Release` > `Any iOS SDK` I look under what should the correct line item and I see the following:

```
Profile doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in your keychains
```

So it sounds like my current cert doesn't allow me to run my app as distribution? I went into the member center and dirtied all related profiles and restarted xcode 4.6 after updating my profiles. Doesn't seem to work.

I also checked my Info.plist and the bundle name is correct there. It's also correct in `TARGETS` > `Summary` > `Bundle Identifier`.

## A private key is missing

I noticed this morning that there is no private key underneath the iPhone Distribution cert in my `Keychain Access` and I suspect that's an issue? I'm an admin in the developer portal so I'm not sure why this wouldn't be working..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you weren't on the **distribution certificate** when it was signed then you need to have someone who IS on the certificate to export their **cert + private key** for you. If in doubt, it's probably the dev portal **agent** who you need this from. The details are found in the answer for the question below:

[Profile doesn't match any valid certificate/private-key pair in the default keychain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11122046/profile-doesnt-match-any-valid-certificate-private-key-pair-in-the-default-keyc)